# Find the limit $\lim \int_{(0,1]} f_n \, d\lambda $ where $ \lambda $ is lebesgue measure

Tags: sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Find the limit $\lim \int_{(0,1]} f_n \, d\lambda $ where $ \lambda $ is lebesgue measure and $ f_n(x)=\dfrac{|\cos(x^{-2})|}{x^{1-1/n}} $ for $ x\in (0,1] $
Is there lebesgue integrable function $g$ such that $ |f_n(x)|\le g(x) $ for all $ n \ge 1 $?

Comment: Try $ g(x)=1/x^{1-1/n}$.

Comment: @user254665: $g$ must not depend on $n$. The OP did not state this explicitly, but it should be clear implicitly. @ OP: You could try to substitute $y = x^{-2}$ first. This will lead to (something like) $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \int_1^\infty \frac{|\cos(y)|}{y} \cdot y^{-1/(2n)}\, dy$. The resulting limit is probably $\infty$ (try the monotone convergence theorem).